# добавление элементов в коллекцию типа "класс"

Tags: java, коллекции

День добрый. Реализовываю добавление элементов в коллекцию, есть такой код:

```
private boolean check = true;
    private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void passengerCheckIn() {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        do {
            passengers.add(new Passenger(...));

        } while (check = true);
    }
```

Passenger это класс с полями информации, со своими `get` и `set`, так вот, при добавления элемента в коллекцию типа `Passenger`, я должен через консоль ввести данные для добавляемого элемента, я могу создать нужные переменные, записать туда данные с консоли через `BufferedReader`, и эти переменные уже указать в конструкторе `new Passenger(...)`, и тогда будет нужный результат, но насколько это правильно? Если будет 100 полей, то создавать 100 переменных? Мне кажется не логично, какие варианты еще есть, как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если объект формируется именно из данных, вводимых пользователем в консоли, то это самый правильный вариант. Несколько улучшить его можно только применением паттерна "строитель" и использованием `Scanner` вместо `BufferedReader`.